# Fancytree dnd5 triggering multiple loads of lazy nodes on hover

Tags: fancytree

I just updated my application from the old Dnd extension to Dnd5 and I'm now seeing multiple/many server AJAX calls (usually 5 or 6) when I hover over lazy-load nodes while dragging. I have only implemented the dragStart, dragEnter, and dragDrop callbacks, and I only see the dragEnter callback being called once when I hover. Is there some special handling or response required from the lazyLoad callback to prevent this? I should also point out that I also updated to the latest version of Fancytree (2.34.0) so perhaps something else has changed that is causing this? (My tree works fine otherwise.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you found a bug. This will be fixed in [Fancytree 2.34.1](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/issues/998)